# The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine Violation error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, httpclient

Please, someone help me. I've been researching this for hours, have tried lots of different suggested fixes, and I'm at a total loss as to why I am still getting this error.

I have an ASP.NET MVC .NET Framwork 4.5 web page with the following code in it:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> LoadData()
        {
            string apiUrl = "http://demo.com/GetData/";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new
                System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var input = new { UserName = "Test", fromDate = "2020-01-01", toDate = "2020-01 01" };
                var response1 = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("Product", input);
                string postresponse1 = "";
                if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper<List<PartOne>>>(data).Data;
                    if (table != null && table.Count > 0)
                    {
                        postresponse1 = ConvertResponseToXML(table.ToList(), input.UserName, input.fromDate, input.toDate).ToString();
                        var responseMSG = _dbCon.InsertResponseXMLDataToDatabase(postresponse1).ToString();

                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

I have this in my web.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy  bypassonlocal="True"  usesystemdefault="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

When I am running project on my dev machine message response return:

> **The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine**

Comment: string apiUrl = "http://demo.com/GetData/"; seems like you are trying https end point with http

Comment: @Always_a_learner End point is http://demo.com/GetData/